# Samsung Galaxy Tab, charging technique through USB Cable

Tags: usb, charging, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

**From** [Galaxy Tab is not being charged through USB Cable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/galaxy-tab-is-not-being-charged-through-usb-cable)

@Chris Stratton

> Tablets have larger batteries than phones and may be unable to
>   sufficiently charge from the half amp limit of a USB port, especially
>   while they are fully on (screen on and full speed processor clock).
>
> Some will barely charge if the screen is off but come with high
>   current 5v "usb-like" wall chargers, others use a higher voltage
>   charger on a custom connector - typically something round. Sometimes
>   the "usb-like" ones are actually special cables with extra pins that
>   tell the tablet that a special high-current charger is being used.

@NobbZ

> The Samsung Galaxy Tab has a loading current of 2 A, but the
>   USB-Specificication only allows 500 mA for the whole bus.

**From** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus

@USB 3.0

> Battery Charging Specification 1.2 released in December 2010. Several
>   changes and increasing limits including allowing 1.5 A on charging
>   ports for unconfigured devices, allowing High Speed communication
>   while supplying a current up to 1.5 A, **and allowing a maximum current
>   of 5 A**

So, **What kind of USB Cable** should be used to **Charge Samsung Galaxy Tablets**, for example Samsung Galaxy Tablet 2 (GT - P5100)

Comment: See my answer at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21144/how-much-power-does-a-galaxy-tab-10-1-charger-need-to-supply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the *cable* is particularly important.  Its the *jack* that the cable plugs into that makes a difference.

[image: Samsung Galaxy Tab USB Power Jack]

Basically, if the tablet can tell that its plugged into a special (high amp) jack, then the tablet will charge more quickly (at 2A), otherwise the tablet will assume its plugged into a standard USB port and charge at the specification limit (500 mA).  The best way to get an adapter that the tablet can identify is to use the official wall adapter.  I believe there is no "standard" way of doing this, so different manufacturers may do different things (e.g., using an Apple USB charger may not work).

You should be able to see what your tablet is doing based on the battery icon in the system tray (assuming its similar to the older Galaxy Tab that I have).  On my tablet the icon will have a small red "X" if its being charged through a "normal" connection, and should have no such "X" if its being charged through a high-amp connection.

See [How much power does a Galaxy Tab 10.1 charger need to supply?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21144/how-much-power-does-a-galaxy-tab-10-1-charger-need-to-supply)

And [Do Samsung tablets have the same USB connector as Apple's iPad?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27954/do-samsung-tablets-have-the-same-usb-connector-as-apples-ipad)

And [Why is charging from computer using USB slower than using an outlet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5262/why-is-charging-from-computer-using-usb-slower-than-using-an-outlet)

Comment: Actually, BOTH the cable and charger are important.  I just ran tests using a tool to report the charging current, and I got values of .6A, .5A, and .2A using a Samsung charger, and values of .460A, .5A, .460A, using the same cables and a different charger. Yes, the longest cable was .2A on the Samsung charger and .460A on the other - no single charger was best. I have ordered some "charge only" cables to test.

Answer (score -1):

Samsung tablets are impossible to charge without the right charger.  The charger was given to you with your tablet and if you lose it you have to buy a new one that will fit because there are many chargers that are wide but don't fit into Samsung Galaxy Tabs. So if you don't have a charger you have to buy one or else your tablet will not be charged until you do so.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that? As the industry went for a [common external power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_External_Power_Supply), I cannot believe in such an "impossibility". See also [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/21158/16575) which proves other chargers (even NoName) work as well.